# get td which contains specific texts and then find its parents and siblings

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find a `<td>` element using `Python Selenium` from a table which contains some specific texts and I am able to get it. But when I call the parent method on selected element it returns me the instance of table not the parent row of the table. What I am doing is as

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.example.com')
WebDriverWait(driver, self.explicit_wait).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "table-id"))
        )
td = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'some texts')]"
parent_row = td.parent    # get the parent of td element
```

but in `parent_row` driver is returning the table instance not the row instance.
Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Webdriver [specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html), there is no way to get the parent element directly using WebDriver. [`.parent` attribute](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.parent) of a `WebElement` in selenium Python bindings is used internally and doesn't refer to the direct parent of an element. It refers to the `WebDriver` instance you called `find_element_by_*` on:

> `parent`
>
> Internal reference to the WebDriver instance this element was found from.

You can get the parent element using xpath:

```
parent_row = td.find_element_by_xpath("..")
```